# How to get multiple self-repeating groups in java reg exes?

Tags: java, regex

Given the following String

```
                                        1_!   37            !   2012071200003588   ! EAKRE     !
```

How can I use a pattern to get `37`, `2012071200003588` and `EAKRE` in different groups by using `m.group(i)`, but using the same (repeating) group braces?

I was trying with this pattern: `.+_!{1}(\s+(\d+|\w+)\s+!){1,}.?`, but it only gave the following result:

```
Groups: 2
Group 0: 13_!   b            !   2012071200005353   ! IAUEB     !
Group 1:  IAUEB     !
```

What I'm trying to get is this:

```
Groups: 2
(not needed) Group 0: 13_!   b            !   2012071200005353   ! IAUEB     !
Group 1: IAUEB
Group 2: 2012071200003588
Group 3: EAKRE
```

The regex has to be self-repeating/must return multiple groups, because my string could have more than three values and all values have to be returned.

My test method looks like this

```
private void testPattern() {
   String test = "13_!   b            !   2012071200005353   ! IAUEB     !";
   Pattern p = Pattern
        .compile(".+_!{1}(\\s+(\\d+|\\w+)\\s+!){1,}.?");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
   if (m.matches()) {
      System.out.println("Gruppen: "+ m.groupCount());
      for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
         System.out.println("Gruppe "+i+": "+m.group(i));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not split by `" *! *"`?

Comment: Regexes may not be the optimal tool for what you want to do. Note that .NET regexes do have an option to retrieve all repeated values of a capturing group, but not Java, though.

Comment: @anubhava I just wanted to know how i would doing it with reg exp, because i think it should be possible somehow. The split is also possible, but not wanted here.

Comment: And what makes you think `split` using `" *! *"` is NOT a regex?

Comment: @anubhava Maybe i was just thinking in wrong dimensions. Could you explain more in detail how you would use your split? I'm not on my computer and would appreciate any code snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the outer group a non-capturing group by starting the inside of the group with "?:". It should look like this:

```
.+_!{1}(?:\s+(\d+|\w+)\s+!){1,}.?
```

I think that is what you are looking for, though your example output doesn't seem consistent with the input. You can also drop `{1}` at the start since it is redundant:

```
.+_!(?:\s+(\d+|\w+)\s+!){1,}.?
```

Comment: Sorry, but this proposed pattern doesn't work (at least) for me.
The Output from my Java-Console looks so:
`Gruppen: 1`
`Gruppe 0: 13_!   b            !   2012071200005353   ! IAUEB     !`

Answer (score 0):

Translating my comments into an answer for OP:

```
String str = "                                        1_!   37            !    2012071200003588   ! EAKRE     !";
String[] toks = str.split(" *! *");

System.out.println(toks[1]); // 37
System.out.println(toks[2]); // 2012071200003588
System.out.println(toks[3]); // EAKRE
```